# How do I integrate crypto options into my website?

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, defi, binance-smart-chain, smart-contract

I'm trying to add crypto options to my website. I've seen the name Ribbon finance a few times as a defi options provider. They don't seem to have the contracts that I'm interested in implementing on Georli Testnet.

Whats the best way to integrate a defi project into your website without being able to test it on the Testnet?

Any other suggestions would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly you want to integrate? Crypto payments or any blockchain logic? Describe better what you need to do.

Comment: @Akall I'm trying to add crypto options to my website with the use of DOVs (but other suggestions that I haven't thought of would also be helpful). I'm planning on initiating a transaction to one of these DOVs from a connected MetaMask wallet, however, during development I would like to test on the Testnet so that I'm not using real crypto.Since this defi project isn't on the Georli Testnet, I'm looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript libraries like [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) or [Web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.2/) to integrate your website with existing Smart Contracts (from DeFi projects) trough [Metamask](https://metamask.io/) extension, that must be installed in the browser of your users, logged with their own private key.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. The thing is that this project contains multiple contracts that interact with each other and I'm not fully aware of how I'd set them up on Hardhat. Someone suggested that I use Tenderly's transaction simulator during testing to help define what sort of transaction I should build and send and then move on to the mainnet. Think this approach will work adequately.

Comment: If the contracts are already deployed, you can previosly set the address. If they need to be deployed, for testing, you can get the address of the deployed contract at initizialization